# get corners of a surface in 2D space

Tags: matrices, geometry

What I know:

I can separate each white surface $x,y$ coordinates of every white pixel to an array of data.

How can I get the $x,y$ corners of each separated white surface?

This is the 2D image : [surface image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcrKn.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your questions lacks details and context. Why are you interested in this question and what have you tried so far? You can find some remarks about how to ask a good question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Take the coords of the points where the black lines intersect.